# Bootstrap grid content position

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I have the following code for django-oscar

```
    <ul class="row">
    {% for product in products %}
    <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">{% render_product product %}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

it works find except on the phone.

As you can see from the screen shot, there is a weird space in the grid system when the size is reduced to the phone (it actually displays like this on the phone). On the desktop, the grid system displays correctly until the size of the browser becomes less than certain px. Is there a way to fix this? (I think I am using bootstrap3)

[Grid system working well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeH8A.png)

[Phone mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADI0Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

what you're looking for is [clearfix](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/clearfix/)

Add this to the parent element, in this case the `row` class

Comment: Thank you for the answer but still having the same problem.. it seems to be fine when I reduce the windows size down to certain width but then suddenly leaves the blank space below that width, even after clearfix application.

Comment: Found the solution! it was because each grid had different height and I had to set min-height.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, in phone mode the In Stock is on different lines, i am assuming this is a height problem. Best solution is to use **flex box** .  Or manually adjust the min height.